# What are my options for a low ceiling garage door opener?

Tags: insulation, garage-door-opener, fire-safety

I have a two car garage with a low ceiling and limited side wall space. Whoever installed the two garage door openers decided that they needed the head room and cut out a strip of drywall running the length of the overhead chain drive. Both doors are on a dual track system. I have no room for side mounted openers.

Recently noticed mice crawling about and disappearing into the ceiling space (my family room is above the garage) so ideally I’d like to seal the garage up for air quality, fire safety, insulation, and pest control.

Comment: Posting some pictures along with some measurements such as the distance from the top of the door to the ceiling.

Comment: What type of door is involved? May also help narrowing down your options.

Comment: Could you perhaps box out the slot in the drywall with additional drywall, basically turning it into a reverse trench?